# Remove "DISTINCT" from Zend_Db_Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-select

You can add "DISTINCT" with the `distinct()` method. But is there any way to remove it after it is added?

Comment: Which version of zend are you using?

Comment: @NandakumarV I'm not sure what version, but my `distinct()` method looks the same as what you posted. The file version is: `@version    $Id: Select.php 23254 2010-10-26 12:49:23Z matthew $`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `distinct` method accepts a parameter `$flag(bool)`. Setting it to `false` will disable the **distinct** from the query. Check

> Zend/Db/Select.php Line 192

```
/**
     * Makes the query SELECT DISTINCT.
     *
     * @param bool $flag Whether or not the SELECT is DISTINCT (default true).
     * @return Zend_Db_Select This Zend_Db_Select object.
     */
    public function distinct($flag = true)
    {
        $this->_parts[self::DISTINCT] = (bool) $flag;
        return $this;
    }
```

NB This is for Zend 1.12

Comment: @ButtleButkus You can find the version using this `echo Zend_Version::VERSION;`